# Weird cocoon like thing in aquarium

Tags: aquarium, identification

I have a 60 liter aquarium with platies, guppies, neon tetras and some shrimp.
I have a couple different plants (don't know the names).

Today I noticed the following on one of the plants:
[image: cocoon like thing]

It's about 8 to 10 mm big.

Can anyone identify what this is?
And tell me if it's something good or bad?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Could you please add some information about the size of this?

Comment: @Allerleirauh added it to the question